# Critical apparatus of a poem

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I am currently setting a poem with a small critical apparatus, using KOMA-script document class "scrreprt". Unfortanetly, using the `\edtext`and `\Afootnote`commands does not seem to work out well. It prints bold typed phrases in my document, saying that there is no edtext for an Afootnote. How can I include the critical apparatus properly. 
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=4cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ }

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@makefntext}{%
    \let\org@makefntext\@makefntext
    \renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{%
        \addtolength{\hsize}{-1cm}%
        \org@makefntext
    }%
}
\makeatother
\flushbottom%macht die Fußnoten gleichmäßig mit einem Xcm Abstand zum Haupttext.


\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\setstanzaindents{0,0}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{.4\columnwidth}
        \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{.4\columnwidth}
    }
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \makeatletter %sorgt dafür, dass die Fußnoten am linken Rand nicht überstehen, sondern mit dem Horizontalstrich gemeinsam schließen.
    \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{
        \parindent 1em%
        \noindent\normalfont\@thefnmark~#1
    }
    \makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \section{Kundrys Klage}
    \beginnumbering
    \setline{705}
    \stanza
    Ich sah das Kind an seiner Mutter Brust,\&
    sein erstes Lallen lacht mir noch im Ohr;\&
    das Leid im Herzen,\&
    wie lachte da auch Herzeleide,\&
    als ihren Schmerzen\&
    zujauchzte ihrer Augen Weide!\&
    Gebettet sanft auf weichen Moosen,\&
    den hold geschläfert sie mit Kosen,\&
    dem, bang in Sorgen,\&
    \edtext{den \edtext{Schlaf}{\Afootnote{Schlummer}} bewacht der Mutter Sehnen,}\&
    \edtext{\edtext{ihn}{\Afootnote{den}} weckt' am Morgen}\&
    der heiße Tau der Mutter-Tränen.\&
    Nur Weinen war sie, Schmerz-Gebaren\&
    um deines Vaters Lieb' und Tod;\&
    vor gleicher Not dich zu bewahren,\&
    galt ihr als höchster Pflicht Gebot:\&
    den Waffen fern, der Männer Kampf und Wüten,\&
    wollte sie still dich bergen und behüten.\&
    Nur Sorgen war sie, ach! und Bangen:\&
    nie sollte Kunde zu dir hergelangen.\&
    \edtext{Hörst du nicht noch ihrer \edtext{Klagen}{\Afootnote{Klage}} Ruf,}\&
    \edtext{wann \edtext{fern und spät}{\Afootnote{spät und fern}} du geweilt?}\&
    Hei! Was ihr das Lust und Lachen schuf,\&
    wann suchend sie dann dich ereilt!\&
    Wann dann ihr Arm dich wütend umschlang,\&
    ward dir es wohl gar beim Küssen bang? --\&
    \edtext{\edtext{Ihr}{\Afootnote{Doch, ihr}} Wehe doch du nicht vernahmst,}\&
    nicht ihrer Schmerzen Toben,\&
    als endlich du nicht wieder kamst\&
    und deine Spur verstoben:\&
    sie harrte Nächt' und Tage,\&
    bis ihr verstummt die Klage,\&
    der Gram ihr zehrte den Schmerz,\&
    um stillen Tod sie warb:\&
    ihr brach das Leid das Herz,\&
    und -- Herzeleide -- starb. --\footnote{Nach Richard Wagner, \textit{Parsifal. Ein Bühnenweihfestspiel}, Textbuch mit Varianten der Partitur, hrsg.~von Egon Voss, Stuttgart: Reclam, 2005 (Reclams Universal-Bibliothek~18362), S.~55/56. Die}\&
    \endnumbering
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a lot of things in your preamble, that don't have anything to do with your problem. It makes spotting your problem easier, if you really [remove _everything_ that isn't needed](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to reproduce the error/illustrate your problem.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "not […] work out well", but obviously it doesn't compile w/o errors. It does though if you remove the superfluous `\edtext{` from the beginning of every line with variants, thus writing `den \edtext{Schlaf}{\Afootnote{Schlummer}} bewacht der Mutter Sehnen,\newverse` etc. The result looks fine to me.

Comment: you can also save yourself quite a bit of typing, if you use `&` instead of `\newverse`. If you write `\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}` you don't have to set the indent to zero for every line again; if is then enough to say `\setstanzaindents{0,0}`

Comment: your l. 82 as a wrong \edtext, without second mandatory argument

Comment: I've edited the MWE and will check with Florian's result.

Comment: Tag `koma-script` removed, because the file reports errors not only wie `scrreprt` but also with `report`.

Comment: It actually worked with Florian's answer. Thank you very much for your help! How can I close this thread?

Comment: Ask @Florian to write a real answer you can accept. Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last in your preamble, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the superfluous `\edtext{` from the beginning of every line with variants, your code compiles without errors.

You can also save yourself quite a bit of typing, if you use `&` instead of `\newverse` to end verse-lines.

Using `\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}` and `\setstanzaindents{0,0}` in the preamble, you don't have to set the indent to zero for every line again.

After clearing out packages and code unrelated to your problem, a functional example could look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung

\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\setstanzaindents{0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \subsection{Kundrys Klage}
    \beginnumbering
    \setline{705}
    \stanza
    Ich sah das Kind an seiner Mutter Brust,&
    sein erstes Lallen lacht mir noch im Ohr;&
    das Leid im Herzen,&
    wie lachte da auch Herzeleide,&
    als ihren Schmerzen&
    zujauchzte ihrer Augen Weide!&
    Gebettet sanft auf weichen Moosen,&
    den hold geschläfert sie mit Kosen,&
    dem, bang in Sorgen,&
    den \edtext{Schlaf}{\Afootnote{Schlummer}} bewacht der Mutter Sehnen,&
    \edtext{ihn}{\Afootnote{den}} weckt' am Morgen&
    der heiße Tau der Mutter-Tränen.&
    Nur Weinen war sie, Schmerz-Gebaren&
    um deines Vaters Lieb' und Tod;&
    vor gleicher Not dich zu bewahren,&
    galt ihr als höchster Pflicht Gebot:&
    den Waffen fern, der Männer Kampf und Wüten,&
    wollte sie still dich bergen und behüten.&
    Nur Sorgen war sie, ach! und Bangen:&
    nie sollte Kunde zu dir hergelangen.&
    Hörst du nicht noch ihrer \edtext{Klagen}{\Afootnote{Klage}} Ruf,&
    wann \edtext{fern und spät}{\Afootnote{spät und fern}} du geweilt?&
    Hei! Was ihr das Lust und Lachen schuf,&
    wann suchend sie dann dich ereilt!&
    Wann dann ihr Arm dich wütend umschlang,&
    ward dir es wohl gar beim Küssen bang? --&
    \edtext{Ihr}{\Afootnote{Doch, ihr}} Wehe doch du nicht vernahmst,&
    nicht ihrer Schmerzen Toben,&
    als endlich du nicht wieder kamst&
    und deine Spur verstoben:&
    sie harrte Nächt' und Tage,&
    bis ihr verstummt die Klage,&
    der Gram ihr zehrte den Schmerz,&
    um stillen Tod sie warb:&
    ihr brach das Leid das Herz,&
    und -- Herzeleide -- starb. --\footnote{Nach Richard Wagner, \textit{Parsifal. Ein Bühnenweihfestspiel}, Textbuch mit Varianten der Partitur, hrsg.~von Egon Voss, Stuttgart: Reclam, 2005 (Reclams Universal-Bibliothek~18362), S.~55/56. Die}\&
    \endnumbering
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```